# Audio stopped working after monitor uses displayport

Tags: sound, speakers, displayport, audio-player

My monitor has built-in speakers.
It's connected to my desktop using HDMI.
Speakers work fine, connection is audio jack.

Audio stopped working. The only thing I can think of is the connection of the monitor: I changed that to DisplayPort. Could this be related?

If not is there any way to troubleshoot sound issues?

Comment: Much depends on the manufacturers implementation of displayport. Audio is supported but may not be [implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Technical_specifications)

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found it myself. Looks like my sound card was suspended after hibernation. This describes it:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting